# Not receiving messages in queue using Masstransit with ActiveMQ

Tags: queue, message, masstransit, activemq-artemis

I have created sample web application, where I used masstransit with ActiveMQ. There are 2 projects 1) Publisher and 2) Consumer.
While sending message to queue, it is neither throwing any error nor receiving by ActiveMQ broker. I have checked the queue but no luck. Checked the settings of ActiveMQ broker, whether it is permission related issue or not but that is also fine.
Not sure what is wrong ?
Here is the publisher code

```
 builder.Services.AddMassTransit(config =>
        {
            config.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
          
            config.UsingActiveMq((ctx, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host("localhost", 61616, c =>
                {
                    //c.UseSsl();
                    c.Username("admin");
                    c.Password("admin");
                });

                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx);
                cfg.EnableArtemisCompatibility();
                
            });
            config.AddRequestClient<SampleMessage>();
        });

        builder.Services.AddTransient<IProducerService, ProducerService>();
```

Here is the controller code

```
public class ProducerController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ProducerController> _logger;
        private readonly ISendEndpointProvider _sendEndpointProvider;
        public ProducerController(ILogger<ProducerController> logger, ISendEndpointProvider sendEndpointProvider)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _sendEndpointProvider = sendEndpointProvider;   
        }

       [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] SampleMessageContracts message)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Start Publisher");
                var endpoint = await _sendEndpointProvider.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("queue:MassTransitConsumer"));
                _logger.LogInformation("End Publisher: send message to the queue successfully");
                return Ok("Send to queue successfully");    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Error in controller: " + ex.Message);
                return BadRequest("Error in controller: " + ex.Message);  
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the queue in activemq broker:

[image: ActiveMQ queue]

Please suggest, not sure, whethere it is security issue or permission or missing some configuration ?

Tried with changing of the configuration of broker.xml but no luck.

Comment: I don't see any consumer configuration in your code above, no AddConsumer.

Answer (score 0):

You should look in the logs, maybe even increase the log level to DEBUG for the MassTransit namespace. It's likely an issue connecting to your broker.

Also, `cfg.EnableArtemisCompatibility();` should immediately follow the `.Host()` configuration, prior to calling `ConfigureEndpoints`.

Comment: I have increase the log level to debug and moved `cfg.EnableArtemisCompatibility();` to below `.Host()`.
In the log level, I can see, it created the temparay endpoint connection which is ` Endpoint Ready: activemq://localhost/VDIP020M010_MassTransit_Example_bus_pyayyynsuhyfbcznbdpzydqjge?temporary=true` but why it creates that. I have specify the queue name in GetSendEndpoint. I can see transport entry in log `Create send transport: activemq://localhost/MassTransitConsumer`
I have.

Comment: You should update your question with the full log of both services (producer and consumer). Also make sure your [messages meet the requirements](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/messages).

Comment: I have checked the log of both the services and also, my message is shared contracts which is used by consumer and producer both. Not sure what else the problem is ?
Do you have any other suggest because stuggling with that from last couple of days ?